# ImageButton over another image

Tags: java, android, button

Well, I recently see whatsapp and tinder application. The "change profile picture" option is the same besides the button over. How we can do this? Is there any lib? or shape to do this ?

[image]

Comment: use `RelativeLayout` and set negetive margin to your image

Comment: I'll try, thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Jorge see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code :

```
<FrameLayout
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="24.0dip"
    android:paddingLeft="0.5dip"
    android:paddingRight="0.5dip"
    android:paddingTop="35.0dip"
    android:background="#ff26a69a"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/profile_image"
        android:layout_width="178.0dip"
        android:layout_height="178.0dip"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_settings_profile"
        app:civ_border_width="2dp"
        app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"/>


    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleInverse"
        android:id="@+id/change_photo_progress"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ImageButton
        style="@style/ActionBarButtonStyle"
        android:background="@drawable/input_circle"
        android:elevation="2.0dip"
        android:id="@+id/change_photo_btn"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center|right"
        android:layout_height="52.0dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2.0dip"
        android:layout_width="52.0dip"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_cam_white" />
</FrameLayout>
```

in drawable folder

**input_circle.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/input_circle_pressed" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/input_circle_pressed" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/input_circle_normal" />
</selector>
```

**Output :**

[image]

Comment: @Jorge glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

add textview inside of imageview

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/linearImage"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imgtimer"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/downcounter"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="6dp"
        android:paddingRight="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txthourr"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLength="2"
        android:text="00"

        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textSize="48dp"
        />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtcolon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLength="1"
            android:text=":"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="40dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txtminutee"
            android:maxLength="2"
            android:textSize="48dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="30"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txtsecc"
            android:maxLength="2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:textSize="26dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="00"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this,alignEnd , alignRight , alignBottom the small image to the big image,and adjust the margin dimensions as per your images.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/bigImage"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="140dp"
            android:background="@drawable/back_image"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/small_image"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/big_mage"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/big_image"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/big_image"
            android:background="@drawable/small_image"
            android:text="" />
</RelativeLayout>
```